# Spring Data Rest: RepositoryRestController deserialization from URI not working

Tags: java, spring, jackson, spring-data, spring-data-rest

My Problem is the deserialization of entities from URI-String.
When I use the by Spring Data Rest generated HTTP interface everything works fine.
I can post the following JSON against my endpoint `/api/shoppingLists` and it will be deserialized to a shopping list with admin as an owner.

```
{
  "name":"Test", 
  "owners":["http://localhost:8080/api/sLUsers/admin"]
```

}

When I use a custom RepositoryRestController this doesn't work anymore. If I post exactly the same JSON to the same endpoint I get this response.

```
{
  "timestamp" : "2015-11-15T13:18:34.550+0000",
  "status" : 400,
  "error" : "Bad Request",
  "exception" : "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
  "message" : "Could not read document: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class de.yannicklem.shoppinglist.core.user.entity.SLUser] from String value ('http://localhost:8080/api/sLUsers/admin'); no single-String constructor/factory method\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@9cad4d2; line: 1, column: 26] (through reference chain: de.yannicklem.shoppinglist.core.list.entity.ShoppingList[\"owners\"]->java.util.HashSet[0]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class de.yannicklem.shoppinglist.core.user.entity.SLUser] from String value ('http://localhost:8080/api/sLUsers/admin'); no single-String constructor/factory method\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@9cad4d2; line: 1, column: 26] (through reference chain: de.yannicklem.shoppinglist.core.list.entity.ShoppingList[\"owners\"]->java.util.HashSet[0])",
  "path" : "/api/shoppingLists"
}
```

My RepositoryRestController:

```
@RepositoryRestController
@ExposesResourceFor(ShoppingList.class)
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired ))
public class ShoppingListRepositoryRestController {

  private final ShoppingListService shoppingListService;

  private final CurrentUserService currentUserService;

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = ShoppingListEndpoints.SHOPPING_LISTS_ENDPOINT)
  @ResponseBody
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
  public PersistentEntityResource postShoppingList(@RequestBody ShoppingList shoppingList,
    PersistentEntityResourceAssembler resourceAssembler) {

    if (shoppingListService.exists(shoppingList)) {
        shoppingListService.handleBeforeSave(shoppingList);
    } else {
        shoppingListService.handleBeforeCreate(shoppingList);
    }

    return resourceAssembler.toResource(shoppingListService.save(shoppingList));
  }
}
```

Could anybody tell me why the deserialization doesn't work anymore with a custom RepositoryRestController (which is suggested by the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers))?

> To take advantage of Spring Data REST’s settings, message converters, exception handling, and more, use the @RepositoryRestController annotation instead of a standard Spring MVC @Controller or @RestController

For the full source code please have a look at the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Yannic92/shoppingList)

Comment: did you find any solution for the above problem i am facing the same issue too

Comment: unfortunately no sorry :(

Comment: https://jira.spring.io/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/DATAREST-687

Comment: MH so still waiting for a fix ;)

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the HAL MessageConverter you should have a Resource as a paramter. Try changing your code to:

```
 public PersistentEntityResource postShoppingList(@RequestBody Resource<ShoppingList> shoppingList)
```

Comment: At the time i asked this question a ShoppingList extends ResourceSupport

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was a difference between the field name at the pojo and the json field. i.e:

```
@Entity
public class Pojo{

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
   @JoinColumn(name = "fk_myother")
   public Other myOther;
...etc
}

POST -> /dao/pojos
{
   "myother":"http://localhost:8034/dao/others/50"
}
```

pay attention that the json field should be "***myOther***" instead.

Hope this helps to someone.